# Edit a veracrypt encrypted drive from linux?

Tags: linux, security, encryption, administrator

I'm looking for some help with decrypting my veracrypt encrypted drive, I know the password and everything needed to decrypt it from boot, but I changed the admin's password on the OS :( I figured I'd move some files around just to regain access to the system, but I can't do that until its decrypted. I'm writing this from a live boot of Linux Mint 15. Is there a tool, or how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VeraCrypt, being a fork of TrueCrypt, is compatible with Linux. you could compile it from source if you had to, but fortunately you don't; there are free Linux builds already available. If it's not in your package repository already, you can grab the Linux version from here: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/releases/view/616110

Note that, if you don't have enough RAM, you may not be able to install much in a live boot. You could try enabling a Linux swap file on some other storage, like a flash drive, or just install VeraCrypt to the flash drive directly (may require non-standard install arguments).

EDIT: Since this is a system drive, you'll need to add the mount option for system mode (without pre-boot authentication). You can do this from the GUI options screen, or by adding `/m sm` to your command line.

Comment: I'll test this out now and get back to you. Thank you for the resource :)

Comment: I was getting this error: Operation failed due to one or more of the following:
 - Wrong mount mode.
 - Incorrect keyfile(s).
 - Incorrect password.
 - Incorrect Volume PIM number.
 - Incorrect PRF (hash).
 - Not a valid volume.

Note: If you are attempting to mount a partition located on an encrypted system drive without pre-boot authentication or to mount the encrypted system partition of an operating system that is not running, you can do so by selecting 'Options >' > 'Mount partition using system encryption'.
I am also using this through the terminal or i would try that option

Comment: Whoops sorry, should have mentioned that originally. You need to use "system mode" mount option, as you discovered. The command line argument to do that is `/m sm` (or `/mountoption system`). See https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command%20Line%20Usage for more info.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Linux installer for Veracrypt on the [downloads](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/releases/view/616110) page currently.

Download the install script, use `bunzip2` to unpack it from the command line (or Archive Manager from the GUI) - then run the installer from a root terminal on your live session.  You can then use that installation of Veracrypt to mount your Windows encrypted volume and browse/modify it, if Mint supports NTFS (which I'm pretty sure it does).